# Add files to empty commit on git?

Tags: git, github

I have been searching for this and i didn't found something clear to understand.

I have a new branch and have make changes on that branch. Then i have commited those changes but i forgot to add the files on that commit. 
So my question is how can i add the files to the empty commit?

What i did:

```
git commit -m "this is my first commit"

git status
      modified: myFile.js
```

So now i have the empty `commit` and i need to add the change `myFile.js` to that `commit`.

What should i do?

Comment: Eso te pasa por uruguayo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your commit by re-running the `git commit` command with the --amend flag, i.e.:

```
git commit -m "this is my first commit" --amend
```

However, this is a valid operation only if you did not push your changes to the server yet. In case you pushed your changes applying the above command risks other synced with your original commit.

Comment: I haven't pushed the changes so i will try this

Comment: So.. i perform the `git add` and then the `git commit...` with the `--amend` command? how git knows that this is not a new commit?

Comment: The `git commit --amend` essentially combines the staged changes with the latest commit. You can read more about it in **[here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/)**.

Comment: This is normally the right way to tweak a previous commit, but heed 
[Jeff Puckett II's note](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36754114/1256452) as well: git will normally not let you commit the same contents again, so if you forget all your `git add`s, it makes no commit at all.

Answer (score 1):

if you didn't add any files to the commit, are you sure you created an "empty" commit?

try running `git log` to see if the commit was actually created.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the modified file to your first commit by amending it.

```
git add myFile.js
git commit --amend
```

you can stage files by doing 
`git add -p` to add modification to tracked files and select the modification you want (even within a file).
or `git add -u` to stage all tracked file
or `git add <first_filepath> <second_filepath> ...` there is several other command like those you can check it out [there](https://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you did not have an empty commit.
If you did not add first, that first commit did not complete successfully.

Second, "`git commit`" gives output similar to "`git status`" when there is nothing to commit, but without honoring the [`advise.statusHints`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-statusHints) configuration variable, which has been corrected with Git 2.25.1 (Feb. 2020).

See [commit 5c4f55f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c4f55f1f62b64f530bd135e5b248ceba7b95708) (17 Dec 2019) by [Heba Waly (`HebaWaly`)](https://github.com/HebaWaly).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9403e5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9403e5dcdd50661a31f7d5103c150a95ab9f0529), 22 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c4f55f1f62b64f530bd135e5b248ceba7b95708): honor `advice.statusHints` when rejecting an **empty commit**
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Heba Waly</sup>
>
> In [ea9882b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea9882bfc4d2850b65eac29ac5152e0d778a744b) (`commit`: disable status hints when writing to `COMMIT_EDITMSG,` 2013-09-12, Git v1.8.5-rc0) the intent was to disable status hints when writing to `COMMIT_EDITMSG,` because giving the hints in the "`git status`" like output in the commit message template are too late to be useful (they say things like "'`git add`' to stage", but that is only possible after aborting the current "`git commit`" session).
>
> But there is one case that the hints can be useful: When the current attempt to commit is rejected because no change is recorded in the index.
>
> The message is given and "`git commit`" errors out, so the hints can immediately be followed by the user.
>
> Teach the codepath to honor the configuration variable.

That means if you try and commit an empty commit, you will now see:

```
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```